# Program Exits Before Finishing

Tags: c, modulo

*Question below context*

**Context:** For this program to be submitted and work properly I need to be able to input 8.68 for the amount that gets scanned in. The program then needs to be able to calculate how many of each coin type needs to be given as well as the remaining balance after you give ***x*** amount of the coin

[What the output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YUW7.jpg)

**Question/Problem:** My program will run until the quarters and get it all correct, once it gets to the dimes, where it has 0 dimes, the program breaks and will exit. *(Even when I use a different amount in the beginning, it will break at a different point if the amount of coin, in this instance the dimes have a value of 0)* What can I do to ensure that it will run and finish the same as the output shown above.

***Code:***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double amount;
    double GST = 1.13;
    double balance;
    int numLoonies;
    int numQuarters;
    int numDimes;
    int numNickels;
    int numPennies;
    int bal;

    printf("Please enter the amount to be paid: $"); //ask how much to be paid
    scanf("%lf", &amount);      //scans the input

    GST = amount * .13 + .005;

    printf("GST: 1.13\n");

    balance = (amount + GST);
    printf("Balance owing: $%.2lf\n", balance);

    numLoonies = balance;
    bal = ((balance - numLoonies)*100);

    printf("Loonies required: %d", numLoonies);
    printf(", balance owing $%1.2f\n", (float)bal/100);

    numQuarters = bal / 25;
    bal = bal % (numQuarters*25);

    printf("Quarters required: %d", numQuarters);
    printf(", balance owing $%1.2f\n", (float)bal / 100);

    numDimes = bal / 10;
    bal = bal % (numDimes * 10);

    printf("Dimes required: %d", numDimes);
    printf(", balance owing $%1.2f\n", (float)bal / 100);

    numNickels = bal / 5;
    bal = bal % (numNickels * 5);

    printf("Nickels required: %d", numNickels);
    printf(", balance owing $%1.2f\n", (float)bal / 100);

    numPennies = bal / 1;
    bal = bal % (numPennies * 1);

    printf("Pennies required: %d", numPennies);
    printf(", balance owing $%1.2f\n", (float)bal/100);

    return 0;
}
```

***Update*** So this is for a school project, should have mentioned that, but I have to use the mod to find the remaining balance, and I had to cast the double into an int as part of the criteria.

*And yes, Canada doesn't have pennies any more but I still have to do it this way*

Comment: ` bal / 1;` is not that useful... what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Shouldn't most of those modulo operations be subtractions? Or be modulo the denomination, regardless of the number of coins?

Comment: Aside: Considering "Loonies", I though Canada does not make change down to "Pennies" anymore.  Is that the case today?

Answer (score 1):

> (Even when I use a different amount in the beginning, it will break at a different point if the amount of coin, in this instance the dimes have a value of 0)

That's a big clue. So let's look at the dimes...

```
bal = bal % (numDimes * 10);
```

So, let's say `numDimes` is 0. Then `(numDimes * 10)` is also zero. What do you think happens when you try to calculate `bal % 0`? If you're not sure, you could put that expression into your program and try it.

Another issue is that I don't think you really mean to say `bal % (numDimes * 10)`. Let's say `numDimes` works out to be 3 for some starting balance... in that case you've got `bal % (3 * 10)` or `bal % 30`. Is that really what you want? That'd give some number between 0 and 29, when you probably really want a number that's less than the value of a single dime. If I've got 79 cents and I *take out* 7 dimes, then `79 % 70` does give the `9` that I should have left over, but it's not the most intuitive way to get there.

Comment: Because of the way `numDimes` is calculated, it will always produce the correct answer as long as `numDimes > 0`. But `bal % 10` will produce the same result.

Comment: @Barmar That'll work, and should avoid the crash, but even that doesn't communicate the OP's real intent as well as another operation. (I don't want to be too specific so that the OP has a chance to figure it out, but I'm sure you can guess.)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Convert money into whole numbers of the lowest unit.

Since code is to count to the "penny", take input and round/convert to whole number of cents.

```
#include <math.h>
double amount;
printf("Please enter the amount to be paid: $"); //ask how much to be paid
scanf("%lf", &amount);
long iamount = lround(amount * 100);
```

Same with GST

```
double GST = 1.13;
long itax = lround(iamount * (GST - 1)); // round to the nearest penny
long ibalance = iamount + itax;
printf("Balance owing: $%.2lf\n", ibalance/100.0);
```

2) Proceed to break down into coins

OP's `bal = bal % (numCoins*CoinValue);` is not the right approach.

```
long CoinDenomination = 100; // 100 cents to the Loonie
long iLoonies = ibalance/CoinDenomination;
printf("Loonies required: %ld", iLoonies);
ibalance %= CoinDenomination;

...

CoinDenomination = 10; // 10 cents to the Dime
long iDimes = ibalance/CoinDenomination;
printf("Dimes required: %ld", iDime);
ibalance %= CoinDenomination;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because of the way numDimes is calculated, it will always produce the correct answer as long as numDimes > 0. But bal % 10 will produce the same result. – Barmar

So what I ended up doing was easier than I originally thought I was going to have to do, I just used mod *coin value*. Thanks for all the comments :)